# SAXParser gives me an empty value for the second tag after 62 element for no clear reason, why?

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I'm creating an app that brings the whole fingerprint attendance registered data for an employee, which contains: date, time, day. I load these data via `SOAP` service, it gives back a string file contains `XML` layout data, and transform it to objects of the same type but with different data and add these objects to `ArrayList` using `SAXParser`. I successfully implemented `SAXParser` -that what I think- and I can make sure of that because I already extracted many objects and added it to the `ArraryList`. The problem is, every time it successfully added 62 objects, suddenly `SAXParser` gives an empty value for the second attribute "TIME" and stop adding new objects to `ArrayList`. I thought at first that because of something wrong in `XML`, but since it's daily check-in and check-out, I noticed that for every new register shows at latest, the oldest object in `ArrayList` is removed. Then it's stops reading XML exactly after adding 62 objects and reading "DATE" attribute, then give blank value for "TIME" attribute and stops reading. Though the remaining app is working fine and linking the `ArrayList` with `RecyclerView` with no issues. But I want to add all objects not only 62.

I tried to debug to check the `qName` value when it's the 63th object "TIME" attribute, in the array `ch` it shows that "TIME" is there, but once it assigns it to String variable it become empty.

Here is the String `xmlResponse` which contains `XML` file example for today:

```
<LIST_ATTEND>
  <ATTEND> //First Object, the latest registered
    <DATE>2019/07/13</DATE>
    <TIME>08:17:49</TIME>
    <DAY>السبت</DAY>
  </ATTEND>
  <ATTEND> //Second Object
    <DATE>2019/07/12</DATE>
    <TIME>21:45:31</TIME>
    <DAY>الجمعة</DAY>
  </ATTEND>

...

<ATTEND> //62th Object, which the last object to be read completely
    <DATE>2019/05/23</DATE>
    <TIME>15:35:07</TIME>
    <DAY>الخميس</DAY>
  </ATTEND>
<ATTEND> //The 63th Object
    <DATE>2019/05/23</DATE>
    <TIME>10:42:40</TIME> //Here SAXParser gives an empty value, and skips all remaining
    <DAY>الخميس</DAY>
  </ATTEND>

...

<ATTEND> //Bottom of the list, oldest registered data
    <DATE>2019/03/03</DATE>
    <TIME>14:50:10</TIME>
    <DAY>الاحد</DAY>
  </ATTEND>
</LIST_ATTEND>
```

Here is java code for implementing `SAXParser`:

```
List<FingerprintAttendModel> fpmList = new ArrayList<>();
String xmlResponse = null;


void readXML(){
    if (xmlResponse != null){
        try{
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(IOUtils.toInputStream(xmlResponse), new DefaultHandler() {

                FingerprintAttendModel fpm;
                String msg;

                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
                    if (qName.equals("LIST_ATTEND")) {
                        fpmList.clear();
                    }
                    if (qName.equals("ATTEND")) {
                        fpm = new FingerprintAttendModel();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    super.characters(ch, start, length);
                    msg = new String(ch, start, length); 
                }

                @Override
                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
                    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
                    if (qName.equals("DATE")) {
                        fpm.setDate(msg);
                    }
                    if (qName.equals("TIME")) {
                        fpm.setTime(msg);
                    }
                    if (qName.equals("DAY")) {
                        fpm.setDay(msg);
                        }
                    if (qName.equals("ATTEND")) {
                        fpmList.add(fpm);

                    }
                    if(qName.equals("LIST_ATTEND"))
                        xmlResponse = null;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem lies in `SAXParser`, not the `fpmList` or any other parts. I checked by debugging, when `ch` array in `SAXParser` catches the DATE of 63th object in the XML and assign it fine, but when it comes to TIME of the 63th object it assign an empty value to String `msg` and skip the remaining process of the `SAXParser`. No actual error I can detect. What should I do? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

A SAX parser is allowed to pass character data in multiple calls of the `characters()` method, and it is your job to concatenate the different parts of the data. It can split it wherever it likes. Your `characters()` method is only keeping the last part that is passed across.